# TypeError DoctrineParamConverter.php (line 46)

Tags: doctrine, typeerror, symfony4

i'm new to symfony framework.
I've installed it by following the tutorial in the official documentation [Setup](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/setup.html).
And i've created a new project with the following commande **symfony new portfolio2 --full**, i ran the commande **symfony server:start** and every think was as suspected a default page showed up with the header  * Welcome to Symfony 4.4.13 .....*.
I faced the problem when i was triying to create my first page by following the official documentation [Create your First Page in Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/page_creation.html).

I've configured the routes.yml file:

```
#index:
#    path: /
#    controller: App\Controller\DefaultController::index
# config/routes.yaml

# the "app_lucky_number" route name is not important yet
app_lucky_number:
    path: /lucky/number
    controller: App\Controller\LuckyController::number
```

i've added the LuckyController.php

```
<?php
// src/Controller/LuckyController.php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class LuckyController
{
    public function number()
    {
        $number = random_int(0, 100);

        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

but when i run the server and try to access http://localhost:8000/lucky/number, the following TypeError is shown

```
        Argument 1 passed to
Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter\DoctrineParamConverter::__construct() 
must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry or null, 
instance of Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry given, 
called in F:\projects\portfolio2\var\cache\dev\ContainerEnYgzlJ\srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php on line 4306
```

**TypeError**

in F:\projects\portfolio2\vendor\sensio\framework-extra-bundle\src\Request\ParamConverter\DoctrineParamConverter.php (line 46)

```
41 /**     
42 * @var array     
43 */
44 private $defaultOptions;  
45  
46 public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry = null, ExpressionLanguage $expressionLanguage = null, array $options = [])    
47 {        
48 $this->registry = $registry;        
49 $this->language = $expressionLanguage;        
50
51 $defaultValues = [
```

i did exactly what the documentation says, also i tried to clear the var\cache but it didn't work.

i'm using PHP  7.2.4, symfony 4.4 and here is my composer.json:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "^1.11",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.1",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.0",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.7",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.2",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
        "symfony/asset": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/console": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/form": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/intl": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/process": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/translation": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/validator": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "4.4.*",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/browser-kit": "^4.4",
        "symfony/css-selector": "^4.4",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "^4.4",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^5.1",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "^4.4"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "4.4.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me fix this issue? (if it possible with details about what causes the problem)

And thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue with the following commande " **composer upgrade** ".